# How dispose connections to services such as Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

My function stores data up Azure Data Lakta Storage Gen 1.
But I got bug

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
```

When I investigated,I knowed that my connection in azure function overcome 8k then it's broken.
Here is my code(Append to file Azure DataLakeStorage Gen 1)

```
//This for authorizing azure data lake storage gen 1
 await InitADLInfo(adlsAccountName);

DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient;

//Here is my code to append data lake storage gen 1
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer)))
 {
    await _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.AppendAsync(_adlsAccountName, path, stream);                         
 }
```

How to dispose that when every append ends.
I try to dispose

```
_adlsFileSystemClient.Dispose();
```

But it didn't dispose anything.My connection will up.

Comment: you can use using DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient clause  since it implements IDisposable

Comment: Tks for reply.I used to using  DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient but it wasn't still dispose

Comment: It will. that is the purpose of the using statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement

Answer (score 0):

I read this 
https://www.troyhunt.com/breaking-azure-functions-with-too-many-connections/[1](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaking-azure-functions-with-too-many-connections/)
and I have made connection down.Just use `DO NOT create a new client with every function invocation.`
Example Code :

```
// Create a single, static HttpClient
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

public static async Task Run(string input)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.com");
    // Rest of function
}
```